# Laravel Session Array Values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I've just started to  test out Laravel. I'm using a form with some fields and trying to validate the inputs using Laravel's built-in validator class.

```
$input = Input::all();
$rules = array(
        'fname' => 'required|max:100',
        'lname' => 'required|max:100',
        'email' => 'required|email',
            );
$validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);
if ($validation->fails()){
            return Redirect::to('inputform')
                            ->with('input_errors', $validation->errors);
            }
```

Everything goes well, and the validation check works. When validation fails, I put the errors in a session variable called `input_errors` and pass it to the view. My problem is that I can't seem to display the errors. I tried a `foreach` loop using the `blade templating engine` as given below:

```
@foreach (Session::get('input_errors') as $message)
    {{ What Should I put here? }}
@endforeach
```

How can I display the errors that are being returned as an array. I tried referencing it as `$message[0][0]` but it didn't work.

Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using Laravel 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for getting the errors is...

```
$messages= $validation->messages();
```

That alone, unfortunately, is not going to return you the messages.  It's going to return a `MessageBag` instance.  This allows you to pull out any specific messages you want or all.

If you want to get all the messages, now you can do do...

```
$errors = $messages->all();
```

That will return an array you could loop through in your view to display errors.  There are also methods for getting errors on a specific field such as...

```
$firstNameError = $messages->first('fname');
```

or

```
$firstNameErrors = $messages->get('fname');
```

I also suggest when sending error messages to the view, to use...

```
->with_errors($validation);
```

That will flash the errors to session and automatically assume you are sending them as an `$errors` variable.  Then you may display the errors in your view with.

```
{{ $errors->first('fname') }}  // Blade approach
<?php echo $errors->first('email'); ?> // Non-blade approach
```

This way, you don't have to add logic to your views trying to determine if the variable exists before you should try and echo it.

http://four.laravel.com/docs/validation

Comment: I get an error message when using withErrors, saying it is undefined function

Comment: @rahules Should work. What's the actual code you're using now? Is your Laravel up-to-date?

Comment: It worked. I had to use with_errors instead of withErrors.  I am using laravel 3.2.14 actually. Accidentally had laravel-4 as tag. Changed it and updated post.

Comment: Okay, I changed the answer to match what worked for you so people are not confused with the snake_case vs camelCase issue in Laravel 3/4.

Comment: Thanks. A small doubt though. Is the semicolon after the blade statements  a standard? or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: Oops good catch.  It shouldn't be there, but it doesn't look like it's giving me a syntax error either.  Thanks.